# curly braces containing number after variable

Tags: php

I have just been asked to fix a client's intranet setup and am trying to reset passwords. The encrypted password variable is created using:

```
sha1($password.$password{1});
```

can someone please explain what the `{1}` means?

I have tried looking but I can't fully understand the responses.

Comment: so hard to test !! `$password="fish"; echo $password{1};`

Comment: manual say "Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements "

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simple $password = "abcd", $newpassword= $password{0};  echo $newpassword outputs "a"

You can access characters of the string using curly braces, so {0} = 1st, {1} = 2nd and so on.

Comment: if you shouldn't downvote a 100% WRONG 'answer' what should you downvote ?

Comment: the index mistake would not invalidate the answer i believe.

Comment: Incorrect information provided to OP, who is looking for the usage of such a syntax is considered wrong. It'll put false information into the OPs head on correct syntax usage & Might cause problems at later stages of development

Comment: daryl if you notice at the time you wrote your comment, the information is correct.